# Weblogic Admin Server vs Managed Servers

Tags: weblogic

What is the difference between a *managed server* and *admin server* in Weblogic parlance? What is the responsibility of both in a standard production environment?

P.S: As I understood from the docs the Admin servers' responsibility is to manage the resources in a domain(a logical grouping of a few managed servers and one Admin server) but what I am not clear about are a few examples of what kind of resources it is responsible for managing?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3887979/289396

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Weblogic defines the roles of Admin/Managed server as follows:

- **Admin Server**

  - can be **only one for a Domain**, which works like a Central Configuration/Monitoring controller for the entire domain
  - runs the **console**, where you can create new managed servers, define DataSources (DB connections), JMS queues, deploy apps to Managed Servers, etc.
- **Managed Server**

  - **additional** WebLogic Server instances
  - you deploy Web applications, EJBs, and other resources onto the Managed Servers and use the Administration Server for configuration and management purposes only. **This is where you run your apps.**
  - Managed Servers can be grouped to **clusters**.
  - one of the examples of a Managed Server is a server running SOA applications, like OSB or BPEL.

See e.g. [Understanding WebLogic Server Domains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/domain_config/understand_domains.html).

Comment: Admin Server and Managed servers run on the same JVM ?

Comment: No, each is running in its own VM, their startup scripts are different. But they can share the hardware.

Comment: I have added some examples for each server.

Comment: J when you say "deploy apps" in Admin Server , what kind of apps you mean? you deploy apps in admin servers or managed servers ?

Comment: You deploy apps through the admin server. Usually you use AdminServer to deploy apps to the Managed servers.

Comment: My understanding is, if we fire a request to WLS, it will got to respective manage server and not Admin server.

Is this correct understanding?

Comment: `can be only one for a Domain`, that means each domain can have one admin server?

Comment: that was true back then. I am not sure if it still applies. I think so.

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic Server Instance is a run time JVM
and it is part of WebLogic Domain.
First Server Instance is called as **Administration Server**
and it is used for Administering the domain.
Other Server Instances in a domain are called **Managed
Server**s and they are used for hosting the deployed
applications.

Answer (score 0):

Admin Server is for managing the administration options for the Weblogic instance hosted. All sorts of configurations which are central are all put up in the Admin Server. The start/stop script of Admin server is separate. You can start/stop Managed Server from the Admin Server console also.

Managed Server is used for deploying/starting/maintain Web Applications. The start/stop script of Managed Server is separate.

Both can run on the same hardware.