# weblogic AS: application deployed on a cluster with two managed servers

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing

I'm on Weblogic AS 10.3.5, I have two managed servers pointed to a cluster, so I have two url, one for the first managed server, the other one for the second.

I will deploy my application on the cluster, so will I reach it on both the url? will the application deployed and running on both the servers?

How does it work? Can you give me some references, please?

Is it clear?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883516/how-does-weblogic-clustering-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be using WebLogic 10.3.5 anymore since it has reached the last stage of support called Sustained Support. Consider to upgrade at least to WebLogic 10.3.6.

Related to your question, I believe you are talking about a Web Application and how to access it. First you need to read about [Load Balancing in a Cluster](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13709/load_balancing.htm#CHDGFIBD). For the web part (JSP and Servlets) basically you have to options: setup a Web Server (like Apache HTTP) to make use of the WebLogic Plug-in, that will then be connected to the WebLogic cluster. The other easier option is to simply use an LBR (load balance router hardware).

These are the "software" solutions you have for Load Balancing your web application in a clustered WebLogic:

> WebLogic Server supports the following Web servers and associated
>   proxy plug-ins:
>
> - WebLogic Server with the HttpClusterServlet
> - Netscape Enterprise Server with the Netscape (proxy) plug-in
> - Apache with the Apache Server (proxy) plug-in
> - Microsoft Internet Information Server with the Microsoft-IIS (proxy) plug-in

You can read more about this options at the [Configure Proxy Plug-ins documentation page for WebLogic 10.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13709/setup.htm#i685302).

Comment: thank you, i'm going to read all the cool stuff you wrote :D So is there no way to contact directly the cluster and been switched to one of the managed servers... :( Thank you

Comment: You need an adress to point to. A cluster does not have an address. It is a set of addresses. :-)